# How to execute an action when user clicks browser action and there is a popup (Chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome-extension, popup

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension that features a browser action and a popup. I need to refresh the content I serve in the popup every time the user opens it, but since the on clicked event will not fire if a popup is assigned to the browser action, I don't know how to trigger the logic to refresh the content.

I'm trying to do this in the background page, but I understand that that might not be the best way. Does anybody have an idea of how to approach this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The popup is created from scratch every time the user opens it, so any javascript file you include using a `<script>` tag will be executed. You can include any logic you need there.

Comment: Thanks very much. The oficial documentation does not talk to much about popups. This solves my problem.